# error while installing ceph storage cluster quick start on Ubuntu

Tags: ceph

I am facing the following errors:

```
[ceph_deploy.mon][ERROR ] RuntimeError: config file /etc/ceph/ceph.conf exists with different content; use --overwrite-conf to overwrite
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 monitors
```

Answer (score 2):

you need synchronize the config to others machine:

```
ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf  admin node01 node02 node03 node04
```

Answer (score 1):

As the message says: Overwrite the configuration with `--overwrite-conf` or remove the configuration via

```
sudo mv /etc/ceph/ceph.conf /etc/ceph/ceph.conf.bak
```

and start the service again.