# How to pass the command "--overwrite-conf" in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ceph

Please see my screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while installing ceph storage cluster quick start on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/681724/error-while-installing-ceph-storage-cluster-quick-start-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Add option after ceph-deploy:

```
ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf mon create-initial
```

Answer (score 0):

You started ceph with the command:

```
ceph-deploy mon create-initial
```

So to pass the additional parameter `--overwrite-conf`, you just append it to your previous command:

```
ceph-deploy mon create-initial --overwrite-conf
```

That's all the magic. Maybe you should google for a beginner's Linux command-line tutorial.

Comment: while executing the command                                                                                      "ceph-deploy mon create-initial --overwrite-conf"   getting the error  "error: unrecognized arguments: --overwrite-conf"

Comment: Then read the output of `ceph-deploy --help` or its manpage `man ceph-deploy`. Probably its exact syntax is described there.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command to get command syntax for --overwrite-conf :

$ ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf
usage: ceph-deploy [-h] [-v | -q] [--version] [--username USERNAME]
                   [--overwrite-conf] [--ceph-conf CEPH_CONF]
                   COMMAND ...

The response does not state this but 'COMMAND' stands

'new', 'install', 'mds', 'mgr', 'mon', 'rgw', 'gatherkeys', 'disk', 'osd', 'admin', 'config', 'repo', 'purge', 'purgedata', 'uninstall', 'calamari', 'forgetkeys', 'pkg')

Typical usage of the --overwrite-conf is to re-execute the 'ceph-deploy admin ..' command so the syntax would be:

$ ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf admin mon01 osd01 osd02 osd03

where mon01 is replaced by the hostname of your monitor node and osd01,osd02,osd03 are replaced by the hostname of your osd nodes